# Are full paths kept private by Firefox, or are they disclosed to websites?

Tags: windows, firefox, security, path, privacy

In Firefox for Windows, when a website requests a file to be uploaded, Firefox displays a standard file selection dialog box.  In that dialog box, the user selects the file to be uploaded.

Unless that file is located in the root of a drive, the file will be located in a folder.  For example, it may be located at: `c:\superuser\example.txt` or it may be located at: `c:\superuser\textfiles\example.txt`

Can the website see the source path (`c:\superuser\example.txt` or `c:\superuser\textfiles\example.txt`), or can it only see the filename (`example.txt`)?

Answer (score 4):

The web server will **not** have access to your local path. It would cause a security risk.

Furthermore, this feature would be useless as websites can be used by multiple operating systems with different filing structures and therefore would be useless to a web server.

Your browser enforces the security in order not to disclose information regarding your local path

EDIT,
As requested, here is an example of a similar question from Stack Overflow.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22184481/retrieving-full-local-path-in-file-upload-control-in-asp-net

Its widely stated that it would just not be possible, even using jQuery. The most a Web Server has access to is the file name.

And yes, I speak from experence, I am a programmer & systems administrator.

Comment: Thank you.  If you have any references for the source of that excellent information, I would greatly appreciate it.  If your source is personal experience as a programmer or system admin, that would be useful to know as well.  Also, is this true for all browsers or just Firefox?

Comment: added more information for you, Also, forgot to mention this is ALL browsers

Comment: The remote website has no access to your file or anything on your computer. You tell your web browser to read the file, and the browser sends the data contents to the server. The mechanism doesn't even exist for it to send the full path, nor is it needed. Note that **file uploads within Java applets** are not constrained, and they can send a list of every file and every path on your computer if you're not careful.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, Harvey!  Very useful.  Does Adobe Flash follow this same rule and offer this same protection?

Comment: Honestly, I am unsure of Adobe Flash, most developers nowadays avoid it